# Match all possible combinations of words using regex

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I've been struggling whole day to get what I want. Maybe you can help me.

Let's say I have a string `DT JJ NN IN JJ JJ NN NNS IN`, ideally, for needed result I would write a regular expression something like this:

```
(<NN.*> +)|(<NN.*> +<JJ.*> *)|(<JJ.*> *<NN.*> +)
```

I want to get a result like all possible combinations, by the example would be like:

1. `NN`
2. `NN`
3. `NNS`
4. `JJ NN`
5. `JJ JJ NN`
6. `JJ JJ NN NNS`
7. `JJ NN`
8. `JJ NN NNS`
9. `NN NNS`

Maybe I am seeking for impossible or should change an attitude. I don't know. Please share any ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what expression you want to match and your requirements, but have you thought about using optional ?, in your pattern?
Something like:

```
((JJ|NN(S)?) ?)*
```

Matches with all your given example cases.